# How to have two structs with same type and name in different header files without conflicts?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, header

I already have, say, a struct smallbox with two primitive variables (int identifier, int size) in it. This smallbox is part of higher structs that are used to build i.e. queues.

Now, I have in a part of my project an issue for which I came up with the solution to expand this smallbox, so it has another piece of information like int costs_to_send_it. While, I am not allowed to change my basis structs, is there a way to expand this struct in some fashion like methods overloading in java or so? Will I still be able to use all operation that I have on my higher structs while having the new struct smallbox with the new attribute inside instead of the old one?

Comment: `struct smallboxextended { struct smallbox base; int extra; /*...*/ };`

Comment: Have them in different header files. Do not include both into the same file. That would be the basic recipe to avoid conflicts. Better would be to not do something by the same name which needs to be different. If there is a rule that you cannot change your structs, then whatever that rule is neede for, it will not be clean anymore. So maybe you can't. Would you like to give more info? Show your code, or at least the definitions. Show how you are using the structs in the way for which they were designed (and for which the rule applies). Show the other way. Maybe https://meta.stackexchange.com/q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence determines the answer: “[Will] I still be able to use all operation that I have on my higher structs while having the new struct smallbox with color attribute inside instead of the old one?” The answer is no.

If the headers and routines involved were completely separate, there are some compiling and linking “games” you could play—compiling one set of source files with one definition of the structure and another set of source files with another definition of the structure and ensuring they never interacted in ways depending on the structure definition. However, since you ask whether the operations defined using one definition could be used with the alternate definition, you are compelling one set of code to use both definitions. (An alternate solution would be to engineer one source file to use different names for its routines under different circumstances, and then you could compile it twice, once for one definition of the structure and once for another, and then you could use the “same” operations on the different structures, but they would actually be different routines with different names performing the “same” operation in some sense.)

While you could define the structure differently within different translation units, when the structure or any type derived from it (such as a pointer to the structure) is used with a routine in a different translation unit, the type the routine is expecting to receive as a parameter must be compatible with the type that is passed to it as an argument, aside from some rules about signed types, adding qualifiers, and so on that do not help here.

For two structures to be compatible, there must be a one-to-one correspondence between their members, which must themselves be of compatible types (C 2018 6.2.7 1). Two structures with different numbers of members do not have a one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: Thank you! This made it clear for me. I solved it by creating other similiar data types and had almost code duplicate of the operations I needed to manipulate my new structs because the original ones know only these structs I wanted to expand. Unfortinately, I couldn't try your compilation suggestion as I had to compile using a given make file.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to expand this struct in some fashion like methods
>   overloading in java or so?

In method overloading, the compiler chooses among same-named methods by examining the arguments to each invocation of a method of that name.  Observe that that is an entirely localized decision: disregarding questions of optimization, the compiler's choice here affects only code generation for a single statement.

> Where I still be able to use all operation
>   that I have on my higher structs while having the new struct smallbox
>   with color attribute inside instead of the old one?

I think what you're looking for is *polymorphism*, not overloading.  Note well that in Java (and C++ and other the other languages I know of that support this) it is based on a type / subtype relationship between *differently-named* types.  I don't know of any language that lets you redefine type names and use the two distinct types as if they were the same in any sense.  Certainly C does not.

There are some alternatives, however.  Most cleanly-conforming would involve creating a new, differently-named structure type that contains an instance of the old:

```
struct sb {
    int id;
    int size;
};

struct sb_metered {
    struct sb box;
    int cost;
}
```

Functions that deal in individual instances of these objects *by pointer*, not by value, can be satisfied easily:

```
int get_size(struct sb *box) {
    return sb->size;
}

int get_cost(struct sb_metered *metered_box) {
    return metered_box->cost;
}

int main() {
    struct sb_metered b = { { 1, 17}, 42 };

    printf("id: %d, size: %d, cost: %d\n",
        b.id,
        get_size(&b.box),
        get_cost(&b));
}
```

Note that this *does not* allow you to form arrays of the supertype (`struct sb`) that actually contain instances of the subtype, nor to pass or return structure objects of the subtype by value as if they were objects of the supertype.